# How to make sure that certain libraries are included before executing script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, object, modernizr

In javascript, I want to know if there's a way to check if a certain library (jQuery, Modernizr, etc.) is present, and if not, throw an alert.

Something like: `require( jQuery ); // if jQuery is undefined, display an alert`
Or:             `require( Modernizr ); // if Modernizr is undefined, display an alert`

I know that this is possible because `Modernizr` and `jQuery` are objects, therefore I made sense to check the `typeof`, like so:

```
function pass() { } // use as noop

var require = function( tool ) {
    if(typeof(tool) == "undefined") {
        alert("[" + tool + "] is not defined.");
    } else {
        pass();
    }
}

    require( jQuery );
```

But that doesn't work, of course, because Chrome's error console says `"Object [jQuery] is not defined."` because I tested for something that doesn't exist. Any tips?

Plenty new to JavaScript, so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass in the tool as a string, then check the `window` object for that key:

```
var require = function( tool ) {
    if (window[tool] === undefined) {
        alert("[" + tool + "] is not defined.");
    } else {
        pass();
    }
}

require( 'jQuery' );
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9vXM2/

Comment: Ahh, thank you! Except it doesn't work unless you add `typeof()` to the scene, like `if(typeof(window[tool]) === ...` Thanks again!

Comment: @ModernDesigner - That's because `undefined` shouldn't be a string. Updated. Check out the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

http://yepnopejs.com/ is what you are after @ModernDesigner

Comment: Yeah, that's useful, but not quite what I am looking for.

Comment: Np .. good question anyway I like the more native soln that you guys have come up with.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to learn JavaScript from the ground up, purely because I'm a beginner, not try to "hop off the wheel". I'm pretty fluent in jQuery already, so javascript seemed like a challenge. Thanks for your contribution! :)

Comment: yepnope is included as part of modernizr.